# optimize wordpress rewrite rule regex

Tags: url-rewriting, regex

i have this codes in my wordpress plugin to add custom url rewrites:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/(.*)/browse/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)',
        'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name[]=$matches[2]&cat_name[]=$matches[3]&cat_name[]=$matches[4]&cat_name[]=$matches[5]',
        'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/(.*)/browse/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)',
        'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name[]=$matches[2]&cat_name[]=$matches[3]&cat_name[]=$matches[4]',
        'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/(.*)/browse/(.*)/(.*)',
        'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name[]=$matches[2]&cat_name[]=$matches[3]',
        'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/(.*)/browse/(.*)',
        'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name[]=$matches[2]',
        'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/?([^/]*)/browse',
        'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );


    flush_rewrite_rules(true);

}, 10, 0);
```

how can i rewrite `(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)` and get `$matches` as array ? first element of `$matches` is city_name variable value and the rest are cat_name array elements.

now everything works but i know the code can be a lot smaller.

Comment: Your rules seem to be weird. With them /browse/a/b will get the exact same output as /browse/b/a which is probably wrong, at least from url esthetics POV.

Comment: @MarkKaplun yes /browse/a/b can works as /browse/b/a but i'll check if a is parent of b later in a function, if it's not user will be redirected to 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

With all part optional with `?`, you obtain one rule to rule them all :

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^cities/(.*)/(browse)?/?(.*)?/?(.*)?/?(.*)?/?(.*)?/?',
    'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name[]=$matches[3]&cat_name[]=$matches[4]&cat_name[]=$matches[5]',
    'top'
);
```

but the `[]` cannot work with the WordPress logic then you need to define the rewrite tag with a number. try that :

```
add_rewrite_tag("%cat_name.%", "([^&]+)");

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^cities/([^/]*)/(browse)?/?([^/]*)?/?(^/)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?',
    'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name1=$matches[3]&cat_name2=$matches[4]&cat_name3=$matches[5]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: I suspect you are going to get unknown index notices when not all the parts are there

Comment: I made some tests and the empty values don't throw notice. but the tests make me find that name with `[]` cannot work. I have edited my answer.

Comment: yeh I commented to the question... this is not the wordpress way o select multiple cats if that what he wants,

Comment: can u suggest a code to get more than 3 cat_names ? like 'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]&cat_name[]=$matches[x in rest].
in my own code i'm limited to 4 cat_name array elements. i need something unlimited.